# Is there a built-in way to get all of the changed/updated fields in a Doctrine 2 entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's suppose I retrieve an entity `$e` and modify its state with setters:

```
$e->setFoo('a');
$e->setBar('b');
```

Is there any possibility to retrieve an array of fields that have been changed?

In case of my example I'd like to retrieve `foo => a, bar => b` as a result

PS: yes, I know I can modify all the accessors and implement this feature manually, but I'm looking for some handy way of doing this

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use
`Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager#getUnitOfWork` to get a `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork`.

Then just trigger changeset computation (works only on managed entities) via `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork#computeChangeSets()`.

You can use also similar methods like `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork#recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet(Doctrine\ORM\ClassMetadata $meta, $entity)` if you know exactly what you want to check without iterating over the entire object graph.

After that you can use `Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork#getEntityChangeSet($entity)` to retrieve all changes to your object.

Putting it together:

```
$entity = $em->find('My\Entity', 1);
$entity->setTitle('Changed Title!');
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$uow->computeChangeSets(); // do not compute changes if inside a listener
$changeset = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
```

**Note.** If trying to get the updated fields **inside a preUpdate listener**, don't recompute change set, as it has already been done. Simply call the getEntityChangeSet to get all of the changes made to the entity.

**Warning:** As explained in the comments, this solution should not be used outside of Doctrine event listeners. This will break Doctrine's behavior.

Comment: The comment below says that if you call $em->computerChangeSets() that it will break the regular $em->persist() that you call later because it won't look like anything is changed. If so, what is the solution, do we just not call that function?

Comment: You are not supposed to use this API outside lifecycle event listeners of the UnitOfWork.

Comment: @Ocramius So how can we check in a controller if the entity has changed?

Comment: You shouldn't. That's not what the ORM is meant to be used for. Use manual diffing in such cases, by keeping a copy of the data before and after the applied operations.

Comment: @Ocramius, it might not be what it's meant to be used for, but it would undoubtedly be *useful*. If only there was a way to use Doctrine to calculate the changes without side effects. E.g. if there was a new method/class, perhaps in the UOW, that you could call to ask for an array of changes. But which would not alter/affect the actual persistence cycle in any way. Is that possible?

Comment: Not in the ORM. We are trying to get rid of a lot of clutter in the UoW, and I think it is out of scope for the current implementation. We may add it in Doctrine 3.x, which is still not planned.

Comment: Is there any news about how to this with Doctrine ? Or do I have to create a diff method in my entity ?

Comment: @PeterFour it doesn't seem to be an interesting/relevant feature. Such a feature is better living outside your entities anyway.

Comment: @Ocramius I hesitated for some time about where to put this diff method, but I thinks it still fits nice to keep the entity logic inside the entity

Comment: See better solution posted by Mohamed Ramrami bellow using $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity)

Comment: Special thanks for the info, not to call `$uow->computeChangeSets()` when updating the entity. Literally took me an hour of debugging! THANKS!

Answer (score 49):

Check this public (and not internal) function:

`$this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity);`

From doctrine [repo](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/577a590987f7d5970f74f1cb770dbdd162201d9e/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L2400):

```
/**
 * Gets the original data of an entity. The original data is the data that was
 * present at the time the entity was reconstituted from the database.
 *
 * @param object $entity
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getOriginalEntityData($entity)
```

All you have to do is implement a `toArray` or `serialize` function in your entity and make a diff. Something like this :

```
$originalData = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity);
$toArrayEntity = $entity->toArray();
$changes = array_diff_assoc($toArrayEntity, $originalData);
```

Comment: How to apply this to situation when Entity is related to another (can be OneToOne)? This case when I run getOriginalEntityData on top-lvl Entity, its related  entities original data is not really original but rather updated.

Answer (score 44):

**Big beware sign** for those that want to check for the changes on the entity using the method described above.

```
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$uow->computeChangeSets();
```

The `$uow->computeChangeSets()` method is used internally by the persisting routine in a way that renders the above solution unusable. That's also what's written in the comments to the method: `@internal Don't call from the outside`.
After checking on the changes to the entities with `$uow->computeChangeSets()`, the following piece of code is executed at the end of the method (per each managed entity):

```
if ($changeSet) {
    $this->entityChangeSets[$oid]   = $changeSet;
    $this->originalEntityData[$oid] = $actualData;
    $this->entityUpdates[$oid]      = $entity;
}
```

The `$actualData` array holds the current changes to the entity's properties. As soon as these are written into `$this->originalEntityData[$oid]`, these not yet persisted changes are considered the original properties of the entity.

Later, when the `$em->persist($entity)` is called to save the changes to the entity, it also involves the method `$uow->computeChangeSets()`, but now it won't be able to find the changes to the entity, as these not yet persisted changes are considered the original properties of the entity.

Comment: It's exactly the same what @Ocramius specified in the checked answer

Comment: $uow = clone $em->getUnitOfWork(); solves that problem

Comment: Cloning the UoW is not supported and can lead to undesired results.

Comment: @Slavik Derevianko so what do you suggest? Just don't call `$uow->computerChangeSets()`? or what alternative method?

Comment: While this post is really useful (it is a big warning to the answer above) it is not a solution by itself. I have edited the accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 7):

It will return changes

```
$entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($entity)
```

Comment: it is so obvious.

Comment: don't forget to do $uow->computeChangeSets(); before

Comment: what if I want to know which entities have changed?

Answer (score 5):

You can track the changes with [Notify policies](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#notify).

First, implements the **NotifyPropertyChanged** interface:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @ChangeTrackingPolicy("NOTIFY")
 */
class MyEntity implements NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...

    private $_listeners = array();

    public function addPropertyChangedListener(PropertyChangedListener $listener)
    {
        $this->_listeners[] = $listener;
    }
}
```

Then, just call the **_onPropertyChanged** on every method that changes data throw your entity as below:

```
class MyEntity implements NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...

    protected function _onPropertyChanged($propName, $oldValue, $newValue)
    {
        if ($this->_listeners) {
            foreach ($this->_listeners as $listener) {
                $listener->propertyChanged($this, $propName, $oldValue, $newValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public function setData($data)
    {
        if ($data != $this->data) {
            $this->_onPropertyChanged('data', $this->data, $data);
            $this->data = $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Listeners inside an entity?! Madness! Seriously, tracking policy looks like a good solution, is there any way to define listeners outside of the entity (I'm using the Symfony2 DoctrineBundle).

Comment: This is the wrong solution. You should look towards the domain events. https://github.com/gpslab/domain-event

Answer (score 3):

So... what to do when we want to find a changeset outside of the Doctrine lifecycle? As mentioned in my comment on @Ocramius' post above, perhaps it is possible to create a "readonly" method that doesn't mess with the actual Doctrine persistence but gives the user a view of what has changed.

Here's an example of what I'm thinking of...

```
/**
 * Try to get an Entity changeSet without changing the UnitOfWork
 *
 * @param EntityManager $em
 * @param $entity
 * @return null|array
 */
public static function diffDoctrineObject(EntityManager $em, $entity) {
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    /*****************************************/
    /* Equivalent of $uow->computeChangeSet($this->em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity)), $entity);
    /*****************************************/
    $class = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
    $oid = spl_object_hash($entity);
    $entityChangeSets = array();

    if ($uow->isReadOnly($entity)) {
        return null;
    }

    if ( ! $class->isInheritanceTypeNone()) {
        $class = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
    }

    // These parts are not needed for the changeSet?
    // $invoke = $uow->listenersInvoker->getSubscribedSystems($class, Events::preFlush) & ~ListenersInvoker::INVOKE_MANAGER;
    // 
    // if ($invoke !== ListenersInvoker::INVOKE_NONE) {
    //     $uow->listenersInvoker->invoke($class, Events::preFlush, $entity, new PreFlushEventArgs($em), $invoke);
    // }

    $actualData = array();

    foreach ($class->reflFields as $name => $refProp) {
        $value = $refProp->getValue($entity);

        if ($class->isCollectionValuedAssociation($name) && $value !== null) {
            if ($value instanceof PersistentCollection) {
                if ($value->getOwner() === $entity) {
                    continue;
                }

                $value = new ArrayCollection($value->getValues());
            }

            // If $value is not a Collection then use an ArrayCollection.
            if ( ! $value instanceof Collection) {
                $value = new ArrayCollection($value);
            }

            $assoc = $class->associationMappings[$name];

            // Inject PersistentCollection
            $value = new PersistentCollection(
                $em, $em->getClassMetadata($assoc['targetEntity']), $value
            );
            $value->setOwner($entity, $assoc);
            $value->setDirty( ! $value->isEmpty());

            $class->reflFields[$name]->setValue($entity, $value);

            $actualData[$name] = $value;

            continue;
        }

        if (( ! $class->isIdentifier($name) || ! $class->isIdGeneratorIdentity()) && ($name !== $class->versionField)) {
            $actualData[$name] = $value;
        }
    }

    $originalEntityData = $uow->getOriginalEntityData($entity);
    if (empty($originalEntityData)) {
        // Entity is either NEW or MANAGED but not yet fully persisted (only has an id).
        // These result in an INSERT.
        $originalEntityData = $actualData;
        $changeSet = array();

        foreach ($actualData as $propName => $actualValue) {
            if ( ! isset($class->associationMappings[$propName])) {
                $changeSet[$propName] = array(null, $actualValue);

                continue;
            }

            $assoc = $class->associationMappings[$propName];

            if ($assoc['isOwningSide'] && $assoc['type'] & ClassMetadata::TO_ONE) {
                $changeSet[$propName] = array(null, $actualValue);
            }
        }

        $entityChangeSets[$oid] = $changeSet; // @todo - remove this?
    } else {
        // Entity is "fully" MANAGED: it was already fully persisted before
        // and we have a copy of the original data
        $originalData           = $originalEntityData;
        $isChangeTrackingNotify = $class->isChangeTrackingNotify();
        $changeSet              = $isChangeTrackingNotify ? $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity) : array();

        foreach ($actualData as $propName => $actualValue) {
            // skip field, its a partially omitted one!
            if ( ! (isset($originalData[$propName]) || array_key_exists($propName, $originalData))) {
                continue;
            }

            $orgValue = $originalData[$propName];

            // skip if value haven't changed
            if ($orgValue === $actualValue) {
                continue;
            }

            // if regular field
            if ( ! isset($class->associationMappings[$propName])) {
                if ($isChangeTrackingNotify) {
                    continue;
                }

                $changeSet[$propName] = array($orgValue, $actualValue);

                continue;
            }

            $assoc = $class->associationMappings[$propName];

            // Persistent collection was exchanged with the "originally"
            // created one. This can only mean it was cloned and replaced
            // on another entity.
            if ($actualValue instanceof PersistentCollection) {
                $owner = $actualValue->getOwner();
                if ($owner === null) { // cloned
                    $actualValue->setOwner($entity, $assoc);
                } else if ($owner !== $entity) { // no clone, we have to fix
                    // @todo - what does this do... can it be removed?
                    if (!$actualValue->isInitialized()) {
                        $actualValue->initialize(); // we have to do this otherwise the cols share state
                    }
                    $newValue = clone $actualValue;
                    $newValue->setOwner($entity, $assoc);
                    $class->reflFields[$propName]->setValue($entity, $newValue);
                }
            }

            if ($orgValue instanceof PersistentCollection) {
                // A PersistentCollection was de-referenced, so delete it.
    // These parts are not needed for the changeSet?
    //            $coid = spl_object_hash($orgValue);
    //
    //            if (isset($uow->collectionDeletions[$coid])) {
    //                continue;
    //            }
    //
    //            $uow->collectionDeletions[$coid] = $orgValue;
                $changeSet[$propName] = $orgValue; // Signal changeset, to-many assocs will be ignored.

                continue;
            }

            if ($assoc['type'] & ClassMetadata::TO_ONE) {
                if ($assoc['isOwningSide']) {
                    $changeSet[$propName] = array($orgValue, $actualValue);
                }

    // These parts are not needed for the changeSet?
    //            if ($orgValue !== null && $assoc['orphanRemoval']) {
    //                $uow->scheduleOrphanRemoval($orgValue);
    //            }
            }
        }

        if ($changeSet) {
            $entityChangeSets[$oid]     = $changeSet;
    // These parts are not needed for the changeSet?
    //        $originalEntityData         = $actualData;
    //        $uow->entityUpdates[$oid]   = $entity;
        }
    }

    // These parts are not needed for the changeSet?
    //// Look for changes in associations of the entity
    //foreach ($class->associationMappings as $field => $assoc) {
    //    if (($val = $class->reflFields[$field]->getValue($entity)) !== null) {
    //        $uow->computeAssociationChanges($assoc, $val);
    //        if (!isset($entityChangeSets[$oid]) &&
    //            $assoc['isOwningSide'] &&
    //            $assoc['type'] == ClassMetadata::MANY_TO_MANY &&
    //            $val instanceof PersistentCollection &&
    //            $val->isDirty()) {
    //            $entityChangeSets[$oid]   = array();
    //            $originalEntityData = $actualData;
    //            $uow->entityUpdates[$oid]      = $entity;
    //        }
    //    }
    //}
    /*********************/

    return $entityChangeSets[$oid];
}
```

It's phrased here as a static method but could become a method inside UnitOfWork...?

I'm not up to speed on all the internals of Doctrine, so might have missed something that has a side effect or misunderstood part of what this method does, but a (very) quick test of it seems to give me the results I expect to see.

I hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Well, if we ever meet, you get a crisp high five! Thank you very, very much for this one. Very easy to also use in 2 other functions: `hasChanges` and `getChanges` (the latter to only get the changed fields instead of the whole changeset).

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is still interested in a different way than the accepted answer (it was not working for me and I found it messier than this way in my personal opinion).

I installed the [JMS Serializer Bundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) and on each entity and on each property that I consider a change I added a @Group({"changed_entity_group"}). This way, I can then make a serialization between the old entity, and the updated entity and after that it's just a matter of saying $oldJson == $updatedJson. If the properties that you are interested in or that you would like to consider changes the JSON won't be the same and if you even want to register WHAT specifically changed then you can turn it into an array and search for the differences.

I used this method since I was interested mainly in a few properties of a bunch of entities and not in the entity entirely. An example where this would be useful is if you have a @PrePersist @PreUpdate and you have a last_update date, that will always be updated therefore you will always get that the entity was updated using unit of work and stuff like that.

Hope this method is helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i want to get old value of relation in the entity, so i use the Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::getSnapshot base on [this](http://kamiladryjanek.com/doctrine2-entity-changeset-for-relations/)

Answer (score 1):

Working with `UnitOfWork` and `computeChangeSets` **within an Doctrine Event Listeners** is probably the preferred method.

**However**: If you want to persist and flush a new entity within this listener you might confront a lot of hassle. As it seems, the only proper listener would be `onFlush` with its own set of problems.

So I suggest a simple but lightweight comparison, which can be used within Controllers and even Services by simply injecting the `EntityManagerInterface` (inspired by *@Mohamed Ramrami* in the post above):

```
$uow = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();
$originalEntityData = $uow->getOriginalEntityData($blog);

// for nested entities, as suggested in the docs
$defaultContext = [
    AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object, $format, $context) {
        return $object->getId();
    },
];
$normalizer = new Serializer([new DateTimeNormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, null, null,  null, $defaultContext)]);
$yourEntityNormalized = $normalizer->normalize();
$originalNormalized = $normalizer->normalize($originalEntityData);

$changed = [];
foreach ($originalNormalized as $item=>$value) {
    if(array_key_exists($item, $yourEntityNormalized)) {
        if($value !== $yourEntityNormalized[$item]) {
            $changed[] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: it does compare strings, datetimes, bools, integers and floats correctly however fails on objects (due to the Circular reference problems). One could compare these objects more in depth, but for e.g. text change detection this is enough and much more simple than handling Event Listeners.

More Info:

- [Serializers and Normalizers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#normalizers)
- [Handling Circular References](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for sync data from a remote `WS` to a local `DB` I used this way to compare two entities (check il old entity has diffs from the edited entity).

I symply clone the persisted entity to have two objects not persisted:

```
<?php

$entity = $repository->find($id);// original entity exists
if (null === $entity) {
    $entity    = new $className();// local entity not exists, create new one
}
$oldEntity = clone $entity;// make a detached "backup" of the entity before it's changed
// make some changes to the entity...
$entity->setX('Y');

// now compare entities properties/values
$entityCloned = clone $entity;// clone entity for detached (not persisted) entity comparaison
if ( ! $em->contains( $entity ) || $entityCloned != $oldEntity) {// do not compare strictly!
    $em->persist( $entity );
    $em->flush();
}

unset($entityCloned, $oldEntity, $entity);
```

Another possibility rather than compare objects directly:

```
<?php
// here again we need to clone the entity ($entityCloned)
$entity_diff = array_keys(
    array_diff_key(
        get_object_vars( $entityCloned ),
        get_object_vars( $oldEntity )
    )
);
if(count($entity_diff) > 0){
    // persist & flush
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me
1.  import EntityManager
2. Now you can use this anywhere into the class.

```
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;



    $preData = $this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity);
    // $preData['active'] for old data and $entity->getActive() for new data
    if($preData['active'] != $entity->getActive()){
        echo 'Send email';
    }
```