# Create entity on entity flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I achieve this:

For example, I have an entity called *Issue*. I need to log changes of a field of this entity.
If a user changes the field *"status"* on the *Issue* entity I need to create a database record about it with the user, who changed the field, the previous status and the new status.

Using: Symfony2 + doctrine2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use an [event subscriber](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html) for that, and attach it to the ORM event listener (in symfony 2, there's [docs about that](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)):

```php
namespace YourApp\Subscriber;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use YourApp\Entity\Issue;
use YourApp\Entity\IssueLog;

class IssueUpdateSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em  = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $updated) {
            if ($updated instanceof Issue) {
                $em->persist(new IssueLog($updated));
            }
        }

        $uow->computeChangeSets();
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(Events::onFlush);
    }
}
```

You can eventually check the changeset as I've explained at [Is there a built-in way to get all of the changed/updated fields in a Doctrine 2 entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057558/any-built-in-way-to-get-all-the-changed-fields-in-doctrine-2).

I left the implementation of `IssueLog` out of the example, since that is up to your own requirements.

Comment: @Patt I did some copy-pasta from one of my projects ;)

Comment: @Ocramius: copy-*pasta* ? Your Italian soul didn't abandon you! P