# Saving the getEntityChangeSet() result in Doctrine EventListener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I need to create changelog in the API for user actions on entities.

For example:

User updates entity Licensor I need to catch the changes and save them in the database in different table.

The first part I was able to do with Doctrine Event Listener

```
class ChangelogEventListener
{
   public function preUpdate($obj, PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
   {
       if ($obj instanceof LoggableInterface) {
            dump($eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet());
       }
   }
}
```

And with marking entity event listeners

```
/**
 * @ORM\EntityListeners(value={"AppBundle\EventSubscriber\Changelogger\ChangelogEventListener"})
 */
class Licensor implements LoggableInterface
```

But I'm not sure if it's even possible and if it makes sense to access the ORM entity manager in a `preUpdate` event.

If it isn't then what's the proper way to do it?

I've tried with Symfony's EventListener instead of Doctrine's but then I don't have access to `getEntityChangeSet(`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Doctrine events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html), and specifically the [preUpdate event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate).  This event is the most restrictive, but you do have access to all of the fields that have changed, and their old/new values.  You *can* change the values here on the entity being updated, *unless* it's an associated entity.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15093259/1307183), which suggests using an [event subscriber](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html), and then persisting to a logging entity.

There is also [this blog post](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ew0r/logging-field-changes-with-a-trigger-like-event-listener-for-auditing-purposes) that uses the `preUpdate` event to save a bunch of changesets to the internal listener class, then `postFlush` it persists any entities that are being changed, and calls `flush` again.  However, I would *not* recommend this, as the [Doctrine documentation explicitly states](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postflush):

> postFlush is called at the end of EntityManager#flush().
>   EntityManager#flush() can NOT be called safely inside its listeners.

If you went the route of that blog post you'd be better off using the `onFlush()` event and then doing your `computeChangeSets()` call after your `persist()`, like the first answer I posted.

You can find a similar [example here](http://phpbeginnertoadvanced.blogspot.com/2016/04/doctrine-events-on-flush-get-entity.html):

Comment: Can I call $uow->getEntityChangeSet(); inside onFlush method is it safe?

Comment: You should be able to yes.

Comment: I was able to do it on onFlush and postFlush events because when the objects were created because I don't use uuid I didn't have ids in onFlush method. I'll accept your answer as directed me to the proper solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are better off using an **event listener** for such thing. What you want is more like a database trigger to log changes. See example below (*tested and works fine*) which logs `User` entity changes in `UserAudit` entity. For demonstration purposes, it only watches `username` and `password` field but you can modify it as you wish.

Note: If you want an **entity listener** then look at [this example](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/faep/listening-on-an-entity-with-an-entity-listener).

**services.yml**

```
services:
    application_backend.event_listener.user_entity_audit:
        class: Application\BackendBundle\EventListener\UserEntityAuditListener
        arguments: [ @security.context ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
```

**UserEntityAuditListener**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\EventListener;

use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\User;
use Application\BackendBundle\Entity\UserAudit;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class UserEntityAuditListener
{
    private $securityContext;
    private $fields = ['username', 'password'];
    private $audit = [];

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContextInterface)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContextInterface;
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) // OR LifecycleEventArgs
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
                if ($args->getOldValue($field) != $args->getNewValue($field)) {
                    $audit = new UserAudit();
                    $audit->setField($field);
                    $audit->setOld($args->getOldValue($field));
                    $audit->setNew($args->getNewValue($field));
                    $audit->setUser($this->securityContext->getToken()->getUsername());

                    $this->audit[] = $audit;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        if (! empty($this->audit)) {
            $em = $args->getEntityManager();

            foreach ($this->audit as $audit) {
                $em->persist($audit);
            }

            $this->audit = [];
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer because it's mentioned on Doctrine documentation PostFlush: "EntityManager#flush() can NOT be called safely inside its listeners."

Comment: That additional flush is strictly for flushing your audit entity, not the original one. Original one is already flushed before the additional flush. That particular sentence in documentation is superficial and cut short. You can always try and see how it works before coming to a conclusion. Example worked and still works perfectly fine for many years for me.

Comment: why don´t you use getEntityChangeSet?