# Save object with original data after form bind

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to make a single revision option for saving certain objects in Sonata Admin.

I though to do this in the following way:

- user edits entry
- form is validated
- the new information is saved as a separate entry (i'll call it `revision`)
- the original object is not modified, except for a relation to the revision

So the code looks something like this (source `Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::editAction()`):

```
$object = $this->admin->getObject($id);
$this->admin->setSubject($object);
$form = $this->admin->getForm();
$form->setData($object);

$form->bind($this->get('request')); // does this persist the object ?

// and here is what I basically want to do:
$object->setId(null);
$orig = $em->getRepository("MedtravelClinicBundle:Clinic")->find($id);
$orig->setRevision($object);
$this->admin->update($orig);
```

The problem is that `$orig` loads the already modified, so `var_dump($orig === $object)` is `true`.

I also tried `$em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($object);` - which grabs the correct data, but as an array, not as an object (this will probably be the last resort).

**So, how can I get (and save) the original object after the form bind took place ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the `clone` keyword to get a independent instance of the object you want to store. It should works by following these steps:

1. Load the original entity (`$object`)
2. Clone the original entity to get a new temporary entity (`$newObject`)
3. Alter the `$newObject` to make it a *new* entry: `$newObject->setId(null);`
4. Bind `$newObject` to the form
5. Save (persist) `$newObject` as a revision
6. Add the revision to (`$object`) and persist it too

I hope that if the form is invalid you won't lose all the data sent by the user.

Just in case, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057558/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-get-all-of-the-changed-updated-fields-in-a-doctrine-2/9057705#9057705) to find the differences between the original entity and the one modified by the form.