# Detecting an change after the validation of an Symfony form with an one-to-one relation

Tags: php, symfony, oop

I use an Symfony product form. That can be changed by an user. After the user saves the form I want to know if there are any changes made in the product.

The form uses the entity of the product. This product has an one-to-one relation with the entity price. As there are multiple one-to-one relation with price for discounts and so on. The price entity has an set of data like `priceType` en `currency` and `value`.

It is an one-to-one one direction, only from product to price. The product entity has the following annotation:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Price")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="price_sales_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $priceSales;
```

After the form is saved and validated I use the following code to compare:

```
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$uow->computeChangeSets();
$changeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($product);
```

The `$changeSet` object gives back the changes made in the product but not the one made in the one-to-one relation. Is there a way to also detect changed in the related entities?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [never use `computeChangeSets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057558/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-get-all-of-the-changed-updated-fields-in-a-doctrine-2) as you are going to alter `UnitOfWork` and this may cause big troubles.

Second, I'm pretty sure that `Product` is the `inversedSide` of your relationship with `Price` (you can verify it checking annotation: if you have `mappedBy` into `Product`'s `price` annotation, than you are into `inversedSide`).

Doctrine looks only for changes at `owningSide` (`inversedBy` annotation) of a relationship.

Once you have switched these sides you can `computeChangeSets` (which I really recommend to do not) or do whatever you need to do.

The best strategy to me (that not involves switching the sides of relation, even if you should stop and rethink if the sides are correct) is to implement a [Doctrine entity listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) and to listen on [`preUpdate`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) event

Comment: It is only an one-to-one one direction, see my added info. Is there not an easier way as an listener as I want to know this in an controller?